# apt-get update "signatures were invalid" error

Tags: apt, updates

When running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm getting this error

```
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

How can I fix this?